# System of Linear Equations + Quadratic Functions problem

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics, applications

Find the quadratic function **y+ax^2+bx+c** whose graph passes through the given points:

- (-1,6)
- (1,4)
- (2,9)

I've attempted this on my own, but when cancelling out one variable, I usually end up cancelling more than one which completely throws me off. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Write a system of three equations from the three givens, for example $a (-1)^2 + b (-1) + c = 6$. Now write the other two from the other points and solve for $a, b, c$ with the $3x3$.

Answer (score 0):

$$a-b+c=6$$
$$a+b+c=4$$
$$4a+2b+c=9$$

Adding the first 2 equations, we have $$2a+2c=10$$.

Times $2$ to the first equation and add to the third equations, we have $$6a+3c=21$$

Dividing by $3$, $$2a+c=7$$.

Solving $2a+c=7$ and $2a+2c=10$, we have $c=3$. Now solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: (1) - (2) gives the value of b.